# Querying for Id's of users in a role and internal subordinates?

Tags: soql

Is there a single or multiple queries that can help me get all the ids of users in a role and the subordinates as well?

I'm thinking multiple queries down the hierarchy with userroleids and what not, but i'm wondering if there is an easier option?

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier way. You can get the entire hierarchy with one query and one for loop using this common grouping pattern:

```
Map<Id, List<UserRole>> hierarchy = new Map<Id, List<UserRole>>();
for (UserRole role : [
    SELECT ParentRoleId, DeveloperName, (SELECT Name FROM Users) FROM UserRole
]){
    if  (!hierarchy.containsKey(role.ParentRoleId))
        hierarchy.put(role.ParentRoleId, new List<UserRole>());
    hierarchy.get(role.ParentRoleId).add(role);
}
```

Depending on your context and use case, it might also be useful to have a map of a record's own Id to itself.

```
Map<Id, UserRole> roles = new Map<Id, UserRole>([/*above query*/]);
Map<Id, List<UserRole>> hierarchy = new Map<Id, UserRole>>();
for (UserRole role : roles.values) { /*same inner loop logic*/ }
```